# Get groupPosition from custom onClick event

Tags: android, expandablelistview, onclicklistener

I have Expandable List View with custom adapter, there is TextView and Button in each row.

In custom adapter's getChildView() i have code:

```
  ImageButton btnAddSigns = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iExp_BtnAdd);
  btnAddSigns.setOnClickListener(((iNweek) mContext).childsClicker);
```

And my custom OnClick for child button in my Activity:

```
    public View.OnClickListener childsClicker = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
    //WORK
    }
```

Now, i can't get **groupPosition** for expandable list group-parent of my clicked button, pleaase help!

P.S. I can't move OnClick listener to adapter class, i need groupPosition in my Activity.

Comment: "P.S. I can't move OnClick listener to adapter class, i need groupPosition in my Activity." - If you make your adapter an inner class of your `Activity`, it can call any of the `Activity` methods passing the `groupPosition` if you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can by implement [onGroupClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener.html) on your listexpandable object !